# Linking to #targets when promoting to homepage

Tags: navigation

On a Drupal 6 site, I want my article to start with a bullet list of section headings, linked to in-page targets; and I want to include this list in the teaser text which is promoted to the homepage.

But the links don't work from the homepage, because Drupal doesn't work out that the on-page target in an article is an off-page target or the teaser, so it doesn't include the node reference.

Is there some way for content authors to achieve this easily?  Maybe there's a module which handles it?

Answer (score 1):

Use URL's relative to the site root. Suppose your node lives at http://example.com/node/123 and your named anchor is called "target", write your link like this:

```
<a href="/node/123#target">Target</a>
```

This should work on the home page and the node page itself.